# Shopware Mysql calculate volumeweight in single query

Tags: mysql, shopware

For shippingcosts calculation, i need to calculate the volumeweight from all articles in the baskets.
I can select a single row or the sum from the basket but not a calculated value from a subtable, how i do this?
`SUM(d.weight)` returns the total weight from all items in the basket but i need the `SUM()` from all basket items from the subselect over the table `s_article_details` with `length*height*width` how the sql must look like?

current situation:

2 items, 1 with 10kg and 1 with 1kg
totalweight: 11kg

the heavy item has the dimension: 500x15x15cm
the other has: 200x20x20cm

the volumeweight is from the heavy one: 112500
the other one: 80000

the volumeweight in sum is 192500

for our shipping company package weight is not 11kg rather than its 19,25kg.

This corrected weight is the basic for the shippingcosts calculation.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MAX() function and you don't need a subselect.
Without testing I would think it is something like:

`MAX(d.length*d.height*d.width*d.weight)`